# Applying for schengen visa(Italy) when longest duration is in Croatia

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, italy, multiple-entry, croatia

I am an Indian citizen. I will be travelling to Rome and then changing flights, not the same airline so will need to enter the schengen zone, and going to croatia the same day. I plan to come back in 12 days back to Italy and stay in Rome for a few days before going back

My doubt is since out of 15 days of my trip, for 12 days I am in Croatia. I will have to apply for a MUlti entry or double entry schengen visa anyways. So i am applying for an Italian visa but can they ask or reject my visa and ask me to first get croatian visa or is my case valid. Coz then this way i wont have to get a seperate croatian visa

Comment: Have you ever had a Schengen visa before? They usually only give you single entry on the first.

Comment: Yes I have. Almost 4 years back. From austria and got multi-entry only